Devspace profile activation for conditionally rendering parent profile - does it work?
I have this profile in my v6 devspace.yaml file.
  - name: staging-review
    parents:
      - profile: suspend-cron-jobs

I want to add another parent profile but I only want it to render if a certain devspace variable is true.
I created and tried to conditionally render a profile named ngrok-webhooks-staging-review.
It should render conditionally if NGROK_PROFILE variable is true.
I'm using the activation approach specified in the devspace docs but it just doesn't seem to work at all https://www.devspace.sh/docs/configuration/profiles/activation. No matter what the variable is set to it always renders ngrok-webhooks-staging-review, even if I just render that profile directly (not through staging-review).
vars:
  NGROK_PROFILE:
    source: command
    command: |-
      if [[ "${devspace.namespace}" =~ "staging-review" ]]; then
        echo true
      else 
        echo false
      fi

  - name: ngrok-webhooks-staging-review
    activation:
      - vars:
          NGROK_PROFILE: true
    patches:
      - op: replace
        path: deployments.users.helm.values.rails.webapp.extraContainers
        value:
          - name: ngrok
            image: ngrok/ngrok:latest
            env:
              - name: NGROK_AUTHTOKEN
                value: 123
            command:
              - "/bin/ngrok"
              - "tunnel"
              - "http://users"
              - "--label=edge=edghts_123"
              - "--log=stdout"
              - "--log-level=debug"

  - name: staging-review
    parents:
      - profile: suspend-cron-jobs
      - profile: ngrok-webhooks-staging-review

I'm running devspace deploy --render --profile=ngrok-webhooks-staging-review cat > "test" and I still see the ngrok image/cmd/env added in. Or even if I just deploy I can see ngrok spinning up which it shouldn't be unless devspace.namespace is staging-review.
I know there is nothing wrong with my cmd or image creation, and if I set the var to just something simple activation still doesn't seem to apply. Am I missing some enable activation setting or something?
Can anyone help me with this?
